# $| f(z)| \le A + B \log {| z|}$ like inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire non-constant complex function and let $A$ and $B$ be given positive real constants. Is it possible that $|f(z)| \le A + B\log{| z|}$ for all complex $z$ such
that $| z| \ge 1$ ?

I've been trying to solve using the fact that since $f$ is continuous in $\{z; |z|\le 1\}$ there exists $M=\sup\{ |f(z); |z|\le 1\}$, and then somehow use the Cauchy's integral formula for derivatives. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Cauchy's integral formula for derivatives is the way to go, but not for a fixed domain. Rather, for every real number $R\geqslant1$ and every complex number $z$ such that $|z|\lt R$, write
$$
f'(z)=\frac1{2\pi\mathrm i}\oint_{|w|=R}\frac{f(w)}{w^2}\mathrm dw,
$$
hence
$$|f'(z)|\leqslant\frac1{2\pi}\cdot\sup\limits_{|w|=R}|f(w)|\cdot\frac1{R^2}\cdot2\pi R\leqslant\frac{A+B\log R}R.
$$
Fix $z$. When $R\to\infty$, the RHS goes to zero. QED.